# why this formulas are equivalent? $\exists x \phi(x) \equiv \neg \forall x \neg \phi(x)$

Tags: first-order-logic

I can't understand why this formulas are equivalent, if exists a x have the property why is equivalent to the opposite?

Comment: Astyx Care to provide a counterexample?  $$\exists x \phi (x) = \exists x \lnot\lnot \phi(x) = \lnot \forall x\lnot\phi(x)$$

Comment: Post was edited since, my comment is no longer valid :) @amWhy

Comment: The OP edited his post, Astyx answered on the first version of the post where the formulas weren't equivalent.

Comment: sorry, i edited the post

Comment: In a world of *males* and *females*, if there is a *male*, then not all humans are *female* (i.e. not-*male*).

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively:

$\neg\forall x \neg\phi(x)$ means that not for all elements $x$ in a certain domain, we know that a statement $\phi(x)$ does not hold. If not for all elements the statement does not hold, there there must be an element for which the statement holds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to analise it in human language: LHS means "there exists $x$ such that $\phi(x)$", RHS is "it is false that for all $x$, $\phi(x)$ does not hold". To see it more formally, it is application of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extension_to_predicate_and_modal_logic) to predicate logic.

Answer (score -1):

the equivalence is misstated ." there exists x Phi(x)" is equivalent to

"NOT for every x NOT Phi(x) . Someone forgot the "NOT" Stuart M.N. It looks now like all the forgotten " NOT"'S have been corrected . (including mine ).